# Differential equation of function used to calculate max value of function

Tags: calculus

$f(x)$ is a real valued differentiable function in $[1, +\infty[$. If $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+f^2(x)}$ and $f(1)=1$... show that $|f(x)|\le 1+\frac{\pi}{4}\forall x\ge 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $f'>0$. This means that $f$ increases, thus $f(t)>f(1)=1$, so $f(t)^2>1$ and then $f'<\frac{1}{x^2+1}$. Integrating this inequality on some interval $[1,t]$ you get $f(t)-f(1)<\mathbb{arctan}(t)-arctan(1)$, or equivalently $f(t)<\mathbb{arctan}(t)+1-\frac{\pi}{4}$. But $\mathbb{arctan}(t)<\mathbb{arctan}(\infty)=\frac{\pi}{2}$, thus the conclusion.

Notice that since $f(1)>1$, you don't need the absolute value in the conclusion.